# Order a string in oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, oracle10g, sql-order-by

I have a string

vl_str_uniq=`D01,D08,D02,D05,D31,D24...` and I would like to perform an ORDER BY on this ON Below `dynamic query`

```
 'SELECT   a.trcode,
               townname,
                     DAYS COUNT,'
            || vl_str_uniq
            || ' FROM   MTXNMGRMTPDT3 a
          WHERE   a.entryno ='
            || p_entryno
            || ' AND a.geocode = '
            || p_geocode
            || ' AND a.bu ='
            || p_bu
            || ' AND a.recstat=0';
```

then the output is 
will be like

trcode ||towname|| dayscount||D01 ||D05||D09||D03  ..

Or whatever unordered string was built in

`vl_str_uniq`

So i want the D01 ||D03||D05||D09 ...to be ordered in the above query ?

how can i achieve this by any means possible ?

Comment: In order to accommodate the 3rd and last requirement - you should "cut the string" after the 3rd occurrence of "||"  (hint: you should use a different regex for `||` and the condition: `where level >...`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from (
select regexp_substr('D01,D08,D02,D05,D10,D11,D12,D20,D21,D22,D30,D31','[^,]+', 1, level) as split from dual
connect by regexp_substr('D01,D08,D02,D05,D10,D11,D12,D20,D21,D22,D30,D31', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
  ) order by split asc
```

OUTPUT:

```
SPLIT
D01
D02
D03
D04
D10
D11
D12
D20
D21
D22
D30
D31
```

Link to ***[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/17541)***

A good explanation of `REGEXP_SUBSTR` can be found [here](http://www-css.fnal.gov/dsg/external/oracle_dcm/v11.2.0.2/olap.112/e17122/dml_functions_2069.htm).
A good explanation of `connected by` can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

Short explanation:

```
select regexp_substr('D01,D08,D02,D05,D10,D11,D12,D20,D21,D22,D30,D31','[^,]+', 1, 1) as split from dual
```

returns the first substring match `D01`. If we change the last parameter to 2:

```
select regexp_substr('D01,D08,D02,D05,D10,D11,D12,D20,D21,D22,D30,D31','[^,]+', 1, 2) as split from dual
```

it'll return the second match: `D08` etc.

`Connected by` is recursively "ordering" the elements according to their "hierarchy" (which is the order they appear in the string - in our example). This order can be viewed by the `level` parameter. Changing the query to:

```
select level, regexp_substr('D01,D08,D02,D05,D10,D11,D12,D20,D21,D22,D30,D31','[^,]+', 1, level) as split from dual
connect by regexp_substr('D01,D08,D02,D05,D10,D11,D12,D20,D21,D22,D30,D31', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
```

will output the substrings according to their "level":

```
LEVEL   SPLIT
1       D01
2       D08
3       D02
4       D05
5       D10
6       D11
7       D12
8       D20
9       D21
10      D22
11      D30
12      D31
```

After we took advantage of that level to display ALL the substrings recursively, we "wrap" the query with another query - for the `order by` (natural order of strings).

Comment: missing an `order by`

Comment: i have updated my question above . Please see if u can help .

Comment: what does level do in regexp_substr and I not quite able to understand connect by   code after that . Please elaborate !

Comment: @alfasin I have updated my question .I want my columns D01,D02,D03 to be listed in the cursor output and not the alias "split" as u have done and performed order by on it .

Comment: @kushal  That's not how we do things here in SO: by changing the question you make my answer (which was good) irrelevant - while what you should have done is post a new questions. That's the second time that you do it (first one was with the order). Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for that .But this was not my intention . Things got clear after you posted your answer. You can still work around.

Comment: @kushal I added an explanation - hope it'll help you to take it from here.